# Oracle SQLPlus listing values with 'having' from multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Goodevening, overflowers!

I am trying to show the CID of the faculty customers who have more than one book_copy checked out, together with the number of book_copies checked-out. I must use the HAVING statement. Faculty members are one of three types under attribute "CATEGORY" of CUSTOMER table. I have tried some different things but now I'm at this point:

```
Select OUT_TO_CID "CID", count(COPY_NUM) "Books checked out" from BOOK_COPY
group by OUT_TO_CID having count(COPY_NUM) > 1;
```

This piece of code works and allows me to show all of the customers with more than one book_copy checked out in the right manner - unfortunately I was supposed to show it for only the faculty members. But how do I get there from here? Is a nested subquery the solution?

OK, so I have now tried with a nested subquery but I'm pretty sure I'm doing it wrong... :D I'm now getting an error in the line of the subquery starting with in.

```
Select OUT_TO_CID "CID",
count(COPY_NUM) "Books checked out"
from BOOK_COPY
group by OUT_TO_CID
having count(COPY_NUM) > 1
in (select CID from CUSTOMER where CATEGORY = 'Faculty')
;
```

These are the tables in question:

```
create table BOOK_COPY
(Copy_Num number(5),
Bookid  number(5),
out_to_CID number(6),
Date_Out date,
Date_Due date,
Held_Until date,
held_for_CID number(6),
CONSTRAINT PKCOPY PRIMARY KEY (Copy_Num,Bookid),
CONSTRAINT FKCID FOREIGN KEY (out_to_CID) references CUSTOMER (CID),
CONSTRAINT FKHeld FOREIGN KEY (held_for_CID) references CUSTOMER (CID),
CONSTRAINT FKBookid FOREIGN KEY (Bookid) references BOOK (Bookid));

create table CUSTOMER
(CID number(6),
First_Name varchar2(12),
Last_Name varchar2(12),
Category varchar2(7),
Balance_Due number(4,2),
SponsorID number(6),
CONSTRAINT pkCID PRIMARY KEY (CID),
CONSTRAINT fkCUSTOMER foreign key (sponsorID) references customer);
```

Please let me know if something about my post is against the rules. And thanks for reading it to the end ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are halfway there since you understand that you must join the 2 tables to be able to filter by category. Therefore, that is what we shall do:

```
Select b.OUT_TO_CID "CID",
count(b.COPY_NUM) "Books checked out"
from BOOK_COPY b
inner join CUSTOMER c on b.out_to_cid = c.cid
where c.category = 'Faculty'
group by b.OUT_TO_CID
having count(b.COPY_NUM) > 1
```

Comment: Oh, thank you sir that was exactly it! It seems I was on my way as you say, but I'm not sure how close hehe :-)